# Oracle Update updating NULL instead of value?

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update

I have a update query something like

```
update employees
set salary = salary - (select sum(salary) from employees where manager_id in (101,102))
where employee_id = 105;
```

The sql above works fine but the below sql is updating NULL instead of value.

```
UPDATE table1 a
SET    a.col1 = a.col1 - (SELECT SUM(b.col2)
                          FROM   table2 b
                          WHERE  b.col3 = 'AA'
                                 AND b.col4 = '1234'
                                 AND b.col5 = '123456789'
                                 AND b.col6 = 'O'
                                 AND b.col7 IN ( 1, 2, 3, 4 ))
WHERE  a.col3 = 'AA'
       AND a.col4 = '2313'
       AND a.col5 = '987654321';
```

Do someone know the reason?

Will it update NULL if salary values have some NULL values in them.
(I know it wont because the inner query returns a number value).

It works fine if I hardcode the values for the inner query but fails if i use bind parameters.
(However a numeric value is returned both when hardcoded or when bind parameter used. )

I just cant  seem to know whats wrong with this simple query.

Comment: By the by here is the original sql `UPDATE TABLE1 a
SET a.COL1 = a.COL1 -
  (SELECT SUM(b.COL2)
  FROM TABLE2 b
  WHERE b.COL3        = 'AA'
  AND b.COL4          = '1234'
  AND b.COL5          = '123456789'
  AND b.COL6          = 'O'
  AND b.COL7          IN (1,2,3,4)
  )
WHERE a.COL3 = 'AA'
AND a.COL4  = '2313'
AND a.COL5  = '987654321' ;`

Comment: Better add these details in the question itself rather than commenting. I have edited your question and added it for you this time.

Comment: Thanks for the help Sir. I will keep this lesson in mind.

Comment: Regarding your question, you could use NVL, such that it updates only when NOT NULL else no change to the column. See my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> salary - (select sum(salary)...

If `salary` or the `sub-query` returns **NULL**, then the entire **expression** results in NULL. **Therefore it would update and set the column value to NULL.**

To avoid this, use **NVL** on the entire expression.

For example,

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE t AS SELECT 1 A FROM dual;

Table created.

SQL>
SQL> SELECT * FROM t;

         A
----------
         1

SQL>
SQL> UPDATE t SET A = A - (SELECT NULL FROM dual);

1 row updated.

SQL>
SQL> SELECT * FROM t;

         A
----------


SQL>
```

So, it updated with NULL value since the expression resulted in **NULL**. Let's use **NVL** to avoid the update when NULL:

```
SQL> ROLLBACK;

Rollback complete.

SQL> UPDATE t SET A = NVL(A - (SELECT NULL FROM dual), A);

1 row updated.

SQL>
SQL> SELECT * FROM t;

         A
----------
         1

SQL>
```

Problem solved!

**To make it more verbose**

The above NVL method is just like `IF NULL THEN REPLACE_VALUE`.

So, you could write a case expression to look it more verbose, it is just expanding the NVL expression:

```
SQL> SELECT * FROM t;

         A
----------
         1

SQL> UPDATE t
  2  SET A =
  3    CASE
  4      WHEN (A -
  5        (SELECT NULL FROM dual
  6        )) IS NULL
  7      THEN A
  8      ELSE (A -
  9        (SELECT NULL FROM dual
 10        ))
 11    END;

1 row updated.

SQL> SELECT * FROM t;

         A
----------
         1

SQL>
```